# Customizing a Beamer Theme

Tags: beamer

I want to produce a beamer presentation exactly as the one attached, it is like the Antibes theme but not exactly. I need to know which theme it is or if is it a customized theme. Antibes theme does not include the Author or the title at the footer, which is exactly what I need to add.
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very quick way to add a footline is using the `hackthefootline` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\usepackage[twocols]{hackthefootline}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you could load some other theme for the footline before loading your Antibes theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Beside Sam Carters easy-to-use answers, an additional way, which loads no extra packages or themes, could be to edit the footline using `\setbeamertemplate` and `\usebeamercolor` commands:

```latex
\usetheme{Antibes}
\author{An Author}
\title{A Long Title}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % Turns Navigation Symbols off
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.2em,wd=.5\paperwidth,right,dp=.6em]{palette primary}%
    \insertauthor\hspace*{1em}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.2em,wd=.5\paperwidth,left,dp=.6em]{title in head/foot}%
    \hspace*{1em}\inserttitle
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\begin{frame}
    Some Content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** As Sam Carter pointed out correctly in the comments, there are different possibilities. The one mentioned above with `\beamercolorbox` may be the most robust way. Throws no *overfull box* error anymore and takes care of possible descenders.

Here the other parts I suggested earlier:

One with the `\dimexpr` version:

```
{\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette primary}} % Just to make the color available in \colorbox
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % Turns Navigation Symbols off
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\colorbox{black}{%
  \parbox[][1em][c]{\dimexpr.5\paperwidth-2\fboxsep}{\hfill \color{white}\insertauthor\hspace*{1em}}}%
\colorbox{palette primary.bg}{%
  \parbox[][1em][c]{\dimexpr.5\paperwidth-2\fboxsep}{\color{white}\hspace*{1em}\inserttitle\hfill}}%
}
```

and here my first idea with simple `\parbox` and `\fboxsep`:

```latex
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
{\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette primary}} % Just to make the color available in \colorbox
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % Turns Navigation Symbols off
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\colorbox{black}{%
  \parbox[][1.5em][c]{.5\paperwidth}{\hfill \color{white}\insertauthor\hspace*{1em}}}%
\colorbox{palette primary.bg}{%
  \parbox[][1.5em][c]{.5\paperwidth}{\color{white}\hspace*{1em}\inserttitle\hfill}}%
}
```

Comment: Your parboxes are too wide. Due to the fboxsep added by the colorboxes, your footline will be wider than the page and cause overfull box warnings.

Comment: Try with `\dimexpr.5\paperwidth-2\fboxsep`

Comment: (or use beamercolorboxes)

Comment: Of course, you're right. Just forgot. I set `fboxsep` to zero. But your versions will also work.

Comment: I would suggest beamercolorboxes. If you copy the definition of one of the footlines from beamer, you will get the same spacing around your text

Comment: a beamercolorbox will also make sure you won't get problems with `\author{An Author}
\title{A Title g}`, which would change the baseline for your parboxes

Comment: Edited it. `beamercolorbox` now is the top suggestion :)

Comment: Great! That is much more robust than the parboxes!